# Why does the value of my variable change before I increment it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I explain the problem in the picture. I go to great lengths for this problem. But one can not find any solution. You can expect help from.

Sorry. My English is very poor, are obvious :)

[image]

Comment: I solved the problem. 
SOLUTION WAY: Added +1 location -> if(i==0kisi_sayisi) i--;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.post` request is an async call, so the logic inside of the callback waits for that call to finish. Meanwhile, you increment `i` after the AJAX call, so `i` gets incremented, the call finishes and then alerts `1`.